# The method 'add' was called on null

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I try to parse my firebase collection and return a list of Service type. 
Here I have replaced my firebase call and parsing with a hard code for simplify it.

```
 Future<List<Service>> _getServices() async {
   List<Service> _servicesList;

      Service service = new Service(
          id: 1,
          name: "name",
          location: "location",
          description: "description",
          image: "image");
      print(service.description);
      _servicesList.add(service);
  return _servicesList;
 }
```

The print in the function returns the right thing but I got this error :

> NoSuchMethodError: The method 'add' was called on null.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

That's because you have not initialized `_servicesList`

```
List<Service> _servicesList = List<Service>();
```

**EDIT:** `List` is now deprecated

Try this to create an empty list.

```
List<Service> _servicesList = [];
```

OR

To create a fixed length list of size 0.

```
List<Service> _serviceList = List<Service>.empty();
```

To create a growable list

```
List<Service> _serviceList = List<Service>.empty(growable: true);
```

Refer [docs](https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html#constructors) for more details on constructors.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you've saved me !

Comment: List<Service>(); method has been deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare like this.

```
// use list bracket []  not use like this  => List addItem;

for(var i=0; i<10; i++){

   addItem.add(i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I declared List in provider. I correct the exception by following the accepted answer, then use hot reload but getting the same exception. After re-starting the app I can see the expected change. So in case you're in provider just remember to re-start the app to reflect the change and again you can avoid the exception by declaring the list like this- `List<object> myList=[]`

Answer (score -1):

below code will fix your error

1 =>   List _list = List();

2 =>   List _list = List();

3 =>   List _list = [];